# Succession of Leadership in the Rambam's Introduction to the Mishnah

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, mesorah-tradition

In the Introduction to the Mishnah, the Rambam lists the leadership through the years from Moshe to Rav Ashi. Is there a source for each link in this chain, showing that successive leaders were associated personally as Rebbe and Talmid, that the latter survived the former, etc.? I tried to create this list but did not get very far before petering out:

YEHOSHU'A SUCCEEDS MOSHE. When Moshe prayed for a successor, G-d chose Yehoshu'a (Num 27:15 to 23). Moshe guided Yehoshu'a (Num 11:28). G-d appointed Yehoshu'a to succeed Moses as leader (Joshua 01:01 to 05).

PHINCHAS SUCCEEDS YEHOSHU'A. Pinchas exercised some leadership during the reign of Yehoshu'a (Joshua 22:13), (Joshua 22:30 to 32). Pinchas survived Yehoshu'a (Bava Basra-15a) and ministered at Beth-El before the Ark (Judges 20:17).

ELI SUCCEEDS PINCHAS

SHMU'EL SUCCEEDS ELI. Eli guided Shmu'el (1 Kings 19:21).

Is there a commentary on the Rambam's book supplying these sources? Or is this just not what the Rambam is saying?

Comment: What kind of source are you looking for? Something like Igeret of Rav Sherira Gaon or do you mean sources via Tanach and Talmud only?

Comment: @Yaacov Deane I'm not picky. I would presume that the Rambam, or Rav Sherira Ga'on, would have had a source in Tanach or Talmud (or Medrash, etc.), but I'm curious to see what's out there.

Answer (score 1):

R. Chaim Kanievsky has a commentary on the Rambam's introduction, titled בשער המלך, in his שיח השדה http://hebrewbooks.org/47700. See also the commentary of the Avodas Hamelech and Yad Peshuta.